# How to make sure user in app's session and google's session are the same when using accounts-google

Tags: meteor

I am using accounts-google on my app and I'd like to solve  rather odd authentication scenario.

*A* logs in so now as an app session and a google session
*A* switches to gmail and logs out there.

Now, mind you that, *A* is actually still logged in on the meteor app.

*B* comes along, logs in to Gmail using his account.

Switches to the meteor app to see that he's logged in, but oddly, logged in with *A*'s account.

This scenario leads to lots of confusions and people unknowingly using other users' accounts where they share computers.

So, basically, I need to users in the meteor session and google session to be the same, and if not, ensure that the current meteor session is invalidated and loginWithGoogle() is called again.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems impossible with Meteor's current accounts package, although one could create a new one using Google's latest googleplus api.

But there seems to exist a workaround by:

1) Set up onBeforeAction hooks on your router to login the user automatically (which asks for credentials if user is not logged in to external service)

```
var loginWithGoogle = function() {
  if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Session.set('loginError', undefined);
    Meteor.loginWithGoogle({
      loginStyle         : "redirect",
      requestPermissions : ['profile', 'email'],
      requestOfflineToken: true
    }, function (err) {
      if (err)
        Session.set('loginError', 'reason: ' + err.reason + ' message: ' + err.message || 'Unknown error');
    });
  }
}

var requireLogin = function() {
  if (! Meteor.user()) {
    if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
      this.render(this.loadingTemplate);
    } else {
      console.log('The app is automatically asking for you to log in.');
      loginWithGoogle();
    }
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
}

Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {except: ['some-special-public-route']});
```

2) Log the user out when they are navigating away from every page (caveat: login/logout gets called everytime the user navigates within the app)

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
        closingWindow();
    });
});

closingWindow = function(){
    console.log('The app is automatically logging you out because you are leaving.');
    Meteor.logout();
}
```

3) improvement area: set a session variable to track user's navigation within the app and run the unload event depending on the variable.